# I keep getting a 'MediaFileUpload' object has no attribute '_fd' error when I try uploading a file to Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCKPjW5JwKo&list=PL3JVwFmb_BnTamTxXbmlwpspYdpmaHdbz&index=3) to learn how to use the Google drive API using Python. I've been able to create folders and list the folders in my drive but when I tried following the tutorial to upload files I got stuck on the **'MediaFileUpload' object has no attribute '_fd'** error.

My code:

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

from Google import Create_Service

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
API_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

folder_id = '**'
file_names = ['1.pdf', '2.jpg']
mime_types = ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg']

for file_name, mime_type in zip(file_names, mime_types):
    file_metadata = {
        'name': file_name,
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload('./Random_Files/{0}'.format(file_name), mimetype=mime_type)

    service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media,
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
```

The Google.py file:

```
import datetime
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

Comment: Looking at other threads on the internet, this error seems to occur when the path you are passing to `MediaFileUpload` is to a file that doesn't exist.  I would suggest putting a line just before the creation of that object that tests for the file's existence, like `os.path.exists('./Random_Files/{0}'.format(file_name)): print("exists")` to see if that's your problem

Comment: @Steve thank you so much. The problem was that in the tutorial he didn't specify that in my working directory the files i want to upload need to be in a folder called 'Random_Files'. So when i was following his instructions i thought the 'Random_Files' refer to the folder in my drive. Thanks for the help again

Comment: glad I could help.  That object's code is definitely broken...it should be giving a better error message when the input file doesn't exist.  - So then that was the problem?

Comment: Hi @i'mgnome could you please formalise your solution into an answer so that other users with the same or similar problems can easily find this solution? Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error while working with GDrive API. Following [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/798) thread, I have realised that misspelled filenames cause the error:

```
media = MediaFileUpload("misspelled_file.extention", mimetype=...)
```

In my case, however, the problem was with working directory, so putting full path to the file in `MediaFileUpload` has resolved the problem as well.